# How to call specific index of bottomNaviagtionbar without pressing it in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to render index 0 page of bottomnaviationbaritem from index page number 2 without pressing bottomBar.
how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:-
call this method when you want to change the index

```
 _handleBottomNaviationBarItemSelection() {
              setState(() {
               _tabController.index =0;
              });
          }
```